# Opengl ES: Copy single layer of 2D array texture to subregion of 2D texture

Tags: opengl-es, textures

I have two textures.
texture A is a 2D array texture with two layers.
texture B is a 2D texture of twice the width of texture A.

I want to copy the contents of the two layers in texture A side-by-side into texture B.

I could render a quad into texture B, while fetching from texture A with a sampler2DArray - but I was hoping for a simpler way to do this?

in desktop GL 4.3+ I could use glCopyImageSubData, but that does not seem to be available on OpenGL ES yet.

Any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a read and write FBO and use glBlitFramebuffer?

Still more code than OpenGL, but a bit simpler than rendering a quad ...